# Programatically querying number of Branch links created via API

Tags: analytics, branch.io

I'm trying to work out how to programatically query the number of Branch.io links created within a period of time, filtered by the usual things like Campaign, Feature, etc.

Using the Query API (https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/query-api/) I seem to be able to find out information once the link has been clicked / actioned upon, but I can't see any way to get the creation data out.

The only way I've found to do this so far is to export data via CSV from the Liveview Links tab.  But this comes in via email, so its really awkward to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The Query API is typically meant for querying pre-aggregated analytics, but if you want to get the link data, please use the v1/url endpoint:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#link-read

Comment: Sorry, I was perhaps unclear - I ultimately want aggregated data about how many links were created.  As far as I can tell the v1/url endpoint doesn't allow me to "discover" what links were created - I can only query them if I know their names.

Comment: There is no way to get the list of links created for your app. As 
@brian mentioned above the query API is used only to retrieve the analytics associated with your links. i.e. clicks, installs, opens. etc.